# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 - Updating Resident IDP from IdentityProviderMgtService

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using `IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.updateResidentIdp()` to update the session timeout. This is my code.

```
IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub stub = new IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub("https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityProviderMgtService");
IdentityProvider idp = stub.getResidentIdP();
IdentityProviderProperty [] properties = idp.getIdpProperties();
for(IdentityProviderProperty property: properties){
    if(property.getName().equals(SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT) && sessionTimeOut!= 0L) {
        property.setValue(String.valueOf(sessionTimeOut));
    }else if(property.getName().equals(REMEMBER_ME_TIMEOUT) && rememberMeTimeOut!= 0L){
        property.setValue(String.valueOf(rememberMeTimeOut));
    }       
}
idp.setIdpProperties(properties);
stub.updateResidentIdP(idp);
```

However, this throws an exception:

```
org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Cannot find authenticator : openidconnect
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.getAuthenticatorIdentifier(IdPManagementDAO.java:2571)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateFederatedAuthenticatorConfig(IdPManagementDAO.java:385)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateFederatedAuthenticatorConfigs(IdPManagementDAO.java:348)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.IdPManagementDAO.updateIdP(IdPManagementDAO.java:1716)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO.updateIdP(CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO.java:297)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderManager.java:636)
at org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementService.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderManagementService.java:74)
```

This exception goes away, if I manually call `idp.setFederatedAuthenticatorConfigs(null);`. But this does not make sense since I should not need to touch any area which I am not updating.  My question is

(1) Is it safe to call `idp.setFederatedAuthenticatorConfigs(null);` in my use case?

(2) Is it a bug in  WSO2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code to update resident Identity Provider. Do not directly use values taken from "stub.getResidentIdP()" because there are some unnecessary values need not be sent.

```
        IdentityProvider identityProvider = new IdentityProvider();

        identityProvider.setEnable(true);
        identityProvider.setPrimary(true);
        identityProvider.setIdentityProviderName("LOCAL");
        identityProvider.setHomeRealmId("localhost");

        IdentityProviderProperty propertySessionIdelTimeout = new IdentityProviderProperty();
        propertySessionIdelTimeout.setName(SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT);
        propertySessionIdelTimeout.setValue(sessionTimeOut);

        IdentityProviderProperty propertyRememberMeTimeout = new IdentityProviderProperty();
        propertyRememberMeTimeout.setName(REMEMBER_ME_TIMEOUT);
        propertyRememberMeTimeout.setValue(rememberMeTimeOut);

        IdentityProviderProperty[] idpProperties = new IdentityProviderProperty[2];
        idpProperties[0] = propertySessionIdelTimeout;
        idpProperties[1] = propertyRememberMeTimeout;

        identityProvider.setIdpProperties(idpProperties);

        stub.updateResidentIdP(identityProvider);
```

For HomeRealmId if necessary you can retrieve the value from the result of stub.getResidentIdP()

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. Does it mean I can use getResidentIdp() only to retrieve an existing value from the idp?

Comment: Yes. It is better if can retrieve value from getResidentIdp() and build new IdentityProvider object for update